# Change color 3D building runtime in Mapbox Android SDK

Tags: android, mapbox

Does anyone have an experience in changing 3D building color runtime in Mapbox Android SDK?

Comment: Somebody for sure has experience with that. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with the fillExtrusionColor property, [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/blob/master/plugin-building/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/plugins/building/BuildingPlugin.java#L107) is an example from the Building Plugin. More information on this property in the [style-spec](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#paint-fill-extrusion-fill-extrusion-color).

Comment: It's for all layer. I need example only for one building by coordinates.